# Normalise Polars list

Tags: python, python-polars

Say I have

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({'a': [[1,2,3], [4, 5, 6, 7]]})
```

I'd like to divide each element in each list by the total in that list. I.e. to get

```py
shape: (2, 1)
┌──────────────────────────────────┐
│ a                                │
│ ---                              │
│ list[f64]                        │
╞══════════════════════════════════╡
│ [0.166667, 0.333333, 0.5]        │
│ [0.181818, 0.227273, … 0.318182] │
└──────────────────────────────────┘
```

How can I do this in Polars?

I've tried using `.list.eval` but get an error:

```py
In [8]: df.select(pl.col('a').list.eval(pl.element()/pl.col('a')
   ...: .list.sum()))
----------------------------------------------------------------
ComputeError: named columns are not allowed in `list.eval`; consider using `element` or `col("")`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list.eval` works, you were just a bit off:

```py
df.with_columns(pl.col('a').list.eval(pl.element() / pl.element().sum()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map_rows method which allows you to process row by row, but list_eval does not work with map_rows so its a trade off. Using a custom function with map rows we can do this in two lines.

First we generate the normalized values for each list item, row by row

```
def norm_list(row):

    row_list = list(row[0])
        
    return tuple([float(i)/sum(row_list) for i in row_list])

res = df.map_rows(lambda t: norm_list(t))

# column_0  column_1    column_2
#      f64       f64    f64
# 0.166667  0.333333    0.5
# 0.181818  0.227273    0.272727
```

Then we can concatenate all columns into a single list

```
res.select(
    pl.concat_list(res.columns)
)

#                       column_0
#                      list[f64]
#      [0.166667, 0.333333, 0.5]
# [0.181818, 0.227273, 0.272727]
```

Comment: `map_rows` is generally an anti-pattern, but thanks anyway for the answer